# Editing ListView based on Primary Key stored in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a listview that has multiple items all the data is currently stored in the Database. i want to be able to edit and delete the selected item via the list view,

```
 String CREATE_DRINK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE drinks (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "type TEXT, " + "volume DOUBLE, " + "time TEXT, " +
            "abv DOUBLE, " +
            "image BLOB )";

    //create drinks table
    database.execSQL(CREATE_DRINK_TABLE);
}
```

After that i have a Cursor Adapter

```
public List<NewDrink> getAllNewDrinks(){
        List<NewDrink> newDrinks = new LinkedList<NewDrink>();

        //1.build the query
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DRINKS;

        //2. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        //3.go over each row,build book and add it to list
        NewDrink newdrink = null;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                newdrink = new NewDrink();
                newdrink.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                newdrink.setType(cursor.getString(1));
                newdrink.setVolume(cursor.getDouble(2));
                newdrink.setTime(cursor.getString(3));
                newdrink.setAbv(cursor.getDouble(4));
                newdrink.setImage(cursor.getBlob(5));


                newDrinks.add(newdrink);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return newDrinks;
    }
```

Once its here i populate all the drinks entered into a list view. However in the list view i want to be able to delete  and edit the drinks enter.

public class DrinkLog_Screen extends Activity {

```
AlcoholDBHelper db = new AlcoholDBHelper(this);
ArrayList<NewDrink> imageArray = new ArrayList<NewDrink>();
ContactImageAdapter adapter;
ListView dataList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_log__screen);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

    List<NewDrink> newdrinks = new ArrayList<NewDrink>();
    newdrinks = db.getAllNewDrinks();
    for(NewDrink nd : newdrinks){
        imageArray.add(nd);
    }
    adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this,R.layout.image_screen_list,imageArray);
    ListView dataList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drink_list);
    dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(dataList);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drink_log__screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void goToMainScreen (View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main_Screen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Here's my xml for the list view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff1a1a1a">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="470dp"
        android:id="@+id/drink_list"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnReturnMS"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnReturnMS"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:text="@string/drink_log" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="@string/return_to_main_screen"
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="goToMainScreen"
        android:background="#ff302f2e"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ... and the question is?

Comment: How do i edit the content that is stored in the database via the list view? Ive read lots of tutorials on the net but i cant implement it into my code. for example (http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-listview-sqlite.html)not in english tho (cant read it)

Comment: by making a layout for edition and then by updating the database ... should be easy after reading the official guides at http://d.android.com

Comment: but how do you select it via the list view? and popluate the same data from the selected list view item  to populate in the edit page?

Comment: it is all in the guide ... prolly in topics about listview and adapters ..

Answer (score 0):

in a listview you can add a setOnItemClickListener like this

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
            YOurClass item = (YourClass) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            /* get method from obtain your id ->getIdYourClass(); from each item from your listview */
            int id= item.getIdYourClass();
            /*
             pass data to custom dialog or another activity and them edit a row
             example-..
            */
            dialogEdit(id);
        } 
    });
```

I hope helps, and sorry for my band english